# Universal proxy configuration for Python urllib3

Tags: python, urllib3

I am trying to use and install a python library according to the instructions at: https://pypi.org/project/ai4bharat-transliteration/. My system is behind a corporate proxy and I am able to use pip and other libraries including urllib3 to access the internet when I am writing code from scratch.

However, in this case, the library wants to access some files over internet when running:

```
`e = XlitEngine("hi", beam_width=10, rescore=True)`
```

And that results in a wall of urllib3 proxy related errors, the first of which is:

```
Downloading Multilingual model for transliteration
SSL certificate not verified...
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1045: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host '172.xx.yy.zzz'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 700, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 996, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 369, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 901, in _tunnel
    (version, code, message) = response._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 277, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='objects.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /github-production-release-asset-2e65be/487173539/4ef3b62d-385b-4a3a-9ab1-a3cc55764ef3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20221220%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221220T101158Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=d24db49d92188df3dbf8a0f1a05126bdaae8bf42289befe734331a41b336f11c&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=487173539&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dindicxlit-en-indic-v1.0.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out')))
```

Where 172.xx.yy.zzz is the url to my proxy and I am guessing that the warning regarding the SSL certificate is just a warning and the problem is the proxy configuration of urllib3.

If so, is there a way to set a universal proxy which will be honored by urllib3 before the library is called by the XlitEngine package installed above. I am reluctant to attempt any changes to the XlitEngine package installed above. I tried posting the issue on Github for XlitEngine but have not received any response so far.

If it is of any consequence, I am using Python 3.8.10 on a headless Ubuntu 20.04 Server Virtual Machine.
Cheers!